# How to loop through nested Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have json data extracted from API I converted it to python dictionary

```
response =    {
      "api": {
        "results": 4,
        "leagues": {
          "22": {
            "league_id": "22",
            "name": "Ligue 1",
            "country": "France",
            "season": "2017",
            "season_start": "2017-08-04",
            "season_end": "2018-05-19",
            "logo": "https://www.api-football.com/public/leagues/22.svg",
            "standings": true
          },
          "24": {
            "league_id": "24",
            "name": "Ligue 2",
            "country": "France",
            "season": "2017",
            "season_start": "2017-07-28",
            "season_end": "2018-05-11",
            "logo": "https://www.api-football.com/public/leagues/24.png",
            "standings": true
          },
          "157": {
            "league_id": "157",
            "name": "National",
            "country": "France",
            "season": "2017",
            "season_start": "2017-08-04",
            "season_end": "2018-05-11",
            "logo": "https://www.api-football.com/public/leagues/157.png",
            "standings": true
          },
          "206": {
            "league_id": "206",
            "name": "Feminine Division 1",
            "country": "France",
            "season": "2017",
            "season_start": "2017-09-03",
            "season_end": "2018-05-27",
            "logo": "https://www.api-football.com/public/leagues/206.png",
            "standings": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Now I am trying to iterate through this nested dictionary I need to extract all third dictionaries inside this nested dictionary keys of needed data are "22", "24", "157", "206"  for better understanding needed dictionary is

```
"22": {
                "league_id": "22",
                "name": "Ligue 1",
                "country": "France",
                "season": "2017",
                "season_start": "2017-08-04",
                "season_end": "2018-05-19",
                "logo": "https://www.api-football.com/public/leagues/22.svg",
                "standings": true
              }
```

i am trying to iterate through it by this code

```
for i in response["api"]["leagues"]["22"]
```

but my issue that API can return any quantity of results and i didnt know keys of needed data. how i can iterate through it if i didnt know keys of needed data

Comment: If you don't know the keys of needed data, what good will iterating through was is there help?

Comment: how i can iterate through it ?

Comment: Dictionaries can be iterated—use `for key in response:` or `for key, value in response.items():`. You still haven't explained how doing that helps if you don't know the needed keys.

Answer (score 0):

The optimal approach could depend on exactly what you are doing with the data as you iterate through the entries, but:

```
response_leagues = response['api']['leagues']
```

restricts to just the stuff you care about.  Then note that

```
[league for league in response_leagues]
```

gives a list of the *keys* in this dictionary (in your example this is `['22', '24', '157', '206']`).

So one way to loop through each of the entries in these lowest level dicts is:

```
for league in response_leagues:
for x in response_leagues[league]:
    #do something with x (the key)
    # and response_leagues[league][x] (the value)
    # for example:
    print(league, x, response_leagues[league][x])
```

with output:

```
22 league_id 22  
22 name Ligue 1  
22 country France  
22 season 2017  
22 season_start 2017-08-04  
22 season_end 2018-05-19  
22 logo https://www.api-football.com/public/leagues/22.svg  
22 standings True 24 league_id 24  
24 name Ligue 2 
...
```

Alternatively, you can get the same result by looping over the key-value pairs (items):

```
for league in response_leagues:
for x in response_leagues[league].items():
    #here x[0] is the key and x[1] is the value
    print(league, x[0], x[1])
```